# elasticsearch search filter equals issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I have an index of person database with the below mapping.

```
{
    "person" : {
                "sex"       : { "type" : "string" },
                "dob"      : { "type" : "string" },         
                "fname"      : { "type" : "string" },
                "lname"      : { "type" : "string" },
                "phone"      : { "type" : "string" }
      }
}
```

My need is to find all matching entries with multiple conditional clauses.

Dob + phone + sex (OR) fname + lname + dob

How do I create a query or filter (using bool) for the above condition. Also I need to query or filter case-insensitive.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting two sets of **must** queries inside a **should** query will meet your requirements, see [bool](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query) for more information:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/people/person/_search?pretty' -d '{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
             {"bool": {
                "must": [
                  {"match": { "sex" : "male" }},
                  {"match": { "dob" : "2000-11-14" }},
                  {"match": { "phone" : "1234 67889" }}
                ]
              }
             },
             {"bool": {
                "must": [
                  {"match": { "fname" : "bob" }},
                  {"match": { "dob" : "2000-11-14" }},
                  {"match": { "lname" : "smith" }}
                ]
              }
             }
            ]
        }
     }
 }'
```

---

> Also I need to query or filter case-insensitive.

the standard analyzer will index the data in lowercase - the [match](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) query will apply the same analyzer to your search term.

Also - it would be a good idea to store you DOB as a date.

Comment: Thanks @olly. I read filters are faster than match. Is there any way to use filters?

Comment: You could replace "query" with "filter". You'd then need to replace "match" with "term" as well. You'd also then need to create a custom lower case analyzer that doesn't tokenise the data and ensure that the values passed to your filter are always lowercase. Functionally what you're doing is a query - you're better off with the flexibility it offers.

TL;DR: Stick to using "query" you probably won't notice the performance difference anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your mapping into a nested object, than you can use the nested filter or query. Since you want to do it case insensitive you would need the match query within the nested query.

More information about the mapping:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html#mapping-nested-type

```
{
    "type1" : {
        "properties" : {
            "person" : {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "sex" : {"type": "string" },
                    "dob"  : {"type": "string" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then create the nested query:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html#query-dsl-nested-query

```
{
    "nested" : {
        "path" : "person",
        "query" : {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                    {
                        "match" : {"person.dob" : "xx"}
                    },
                    {
                        "range" : {"person.sex" : "male"}
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```